# Runtime.getRuntime().exec Hangs

Tags: java, runtime.exec

I have a java jar file which inturn calls a java program (command).

Command generated works fine when i run it in command promt.

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C "+ Command);

        BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new 
                     InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

                BufferedReader stdErr = new BufferedReader(new 
                     InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));

            String output=null;
            while((output=stdIn.readLine())!=null)
            {
                System.out.println("output is:"+output);
                out.write(output);
                out.newLine();

            }
            while((output=stdErr.readLine())!=null)
            {
                System.out.println("error output is:"+output);
                out.write(output);
                out.newLine();

            } 
            try {
process.waitFor();
....
....
....
```

I tried ProcessBuilder:

```
ProcessBuilder proc = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/C", Command);         proc.redirectErrorStream(true);
proc.start();
```

But this throws error as:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "java -Xmx1024M ......"
CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

I can run the same command in promt which works absolutely fine.

Answer (score 1):

With

```
 new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/C", Command);
```

you have used the varargs overload of the constructor. This means that the command is assumed to be already parsed into the arguments. However, you are passing the complete `Command` as a single argument, which means that `cmd` will interpret the whole command line `java -Xmx...` as just the command (file name) to run.

Either stick to the single string, relying on the `ProcessBuilder` class to parse it, or pre-parse everything.

As for the hanging issue you have, there may be several causes:

- maybe your `out` stream is blocking;
- maybe the program you are starting writes to `stderr`, which you don't read at all until it is already too late (the program has ended).

Your second approach would fix this by merging `stdout` and `stderr`.

Comment: Thank you Marko. Command is like this: "java -Xmx1024M -Djava.util.logging.file="log//logs.txt" -classpath lib\tool.jar;lib\solver.jar com.tool.section.MainFunc -parameter redo section logo.propery C:\SectionTool" I am not sure how to pass this into ProcessBuilder now :(

Comment: Somethnig like `("cmd.exe", "/c", "java", "-Xmx1024m", "-Djava.util.logging.file=log/logs.txt", ` and so on.

Comment: Thanks Marko. :(ah.. i just saw a code flow and see that we need to followup on the same code as of now.. means we need to find a solution with Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C "+ Command); only. This is because lot of codes already been written using BufferedReader which will have to rewrite if we use ProcessBuilder. Any way we could get through with this?

Comment: There's no reason why you couldn't use a `BufferedReader` with a process created by the `ProcessBuilder`. Once you create the `Process` instance, you are at exactly the same spot as if you had created it the old way.